# YoutTube API Access Limit

Tags: api, architecture, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

We are in the process of integrating the `YouTube API` into our site as a way to solve our current pressing need.

We want to figure out the `best possible architecture` for `video integration` into our website.
Specifications:

- Users upload video to the site via our UI
- We direct the video to YouTube for storage and subsequent retrieval, delete, etc.
- Viewers view the video on our site using YouTube embedded player

Questions:

- The rate of video upload per day to our site can go as high as 500 videos and we'd like to know if YouTube has any video upload limit, both per day and per hour.
- Do you think this is a good idea/approach to solving our video integration problem.

(hint: we use Azure blob storage so storing data in the cloud is a trivial thing for us. We just want the best, fastest and cheapest way of going about this.)

Please kindly advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Youtube API docs don't list any daily upload limits but it does say:

> You may not build an application that duplicates or mimics a substantial part of the YouTube service without adding significant value.

I'd read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) closely.

Based on the limited information available, it sounds like a reasonable solution. Just make sure that users are clear their uploads will be on YouTube (and therefore searchable or available via public URLs) when they upload so they know where their data is.

Comment: Oh I get that. Thanks for the reply.